# hide divs when selecting new rado button using toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on a radio button, if it's the last one in the list, it shows all of the hidden divs and doesn't close all open divs when I select another radio button. I know I'm close...but missing something.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input').on('change',function(){
      $(".groupNumber").hide().filter(":lt(" + this.value + ")").slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });
```

I thought I was taking care of it by having the "hide" at the beginning of the chain.

#### Html

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="25"><input type="radio" name="rNumber" value="1"></td>
<td width="25"><input type="radio" name="rNumber" value="2"></td>
<td width="25"><input type="radio" name="rNumber" value="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The divs are as follows:

```
<div id="grp1" class="groupNumber">Content Here</div>
<div id="grp2" class="groupNumber">Content Here</div>
<div id="grp3" class="groupNumber">Content Here</div>
```

What I want is the div for the corresponding radiobutton to be visible and to close any others that may be open.

Comment: What, exactly, is it that you want to happen? And what's your HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your opposition to the site's comment system (code should always be added to the question, it's frankly unreadable in comments anyway); but perhaps that's because I'm used to it. You can always try and post a feature-request, over at [Meta] though, if you feel it's lacking in usability? (Note: my comment was a response to content since (rightly) removed from the question; check the edit-history for context.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because yo are using `lt`, you should use `eq` instead. try this.

using `lt` you are getting all the divs less that the index value to be shown so it is displaying that one and all previous ones. instead just use `eq` to get the div to be shown from the collection.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('input').on('change',function(){
       $(".groupNumber").hide().eq((+this.value -1)).slideToggle("slow");//Probably Slide toggle probably doesn't make sense here as change event won't be triggered if you select the same option again.
      });
    });
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLdqf/)

Comment: @Amidude Wow that was it? you are welcome. It was my guess on how your html look. Saw that you updated your question now with your markup. :) Please consider placing your relevant mark up too next time you post so that you will get quick answers as you post your question.. :)